# Low basement ceiling, how high should cabinets be?

Tags: basement, kitchens, ceiling, cabinets

I am creating basement suite. The ceiling is 6' 8". I plan to install a drop ceiling, so it  will be around 6' 6" when that is done.

How high should my upper kitchen cabinets be? I've read that they are supposed to start at 54". If the shortest cabinets are 30" and the ceiling is only 78" high, these won't fit.

Should I cut the cabinets? Or install them them lower?

Comment: Have fun getting an occupancy permit. https://buildingcodetrainer.com/residential-ceiling-heights-per-code/

Comment: actually it's only 6' 4" height requirement where I live.

Comment: 6'-4" is a magic number in IRC R305.1: "Beams, girders, ducts or other obstructions in basements containing habitable space shall be permitted to project to within 6 feet 4 inches (1931 mm) of the finished floor." You're not extrapolating this exception for @Ecnerwal's 7'-0" to the whole area, are you?

Comment: This is a decorating/design question. There is no "right" answer.

Comment: My standard kitchen cabinets come in ~18, 24, and 30 inches, so custom/semi custom should not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Standard counter height is 36". 54" - 36" = 18". So the usual distance between the counter and the bottom of the cabinets is 18". Keep in mind that upper cabinets are also usually not as deep as counters: 12" vs. 24".

All of that means that if you use 30" tall upper cabinets above 36" counters on a 78" wall that you will have 12" instead of 18" between the counter and the cabinets. If you use the under-cabinet space mainly for storage - e.g., slide the toaster and food processor, etc. out of the way when not in use, you will be fine. On the other hand, some things such as a dish drying rack may be a bit harder to fully use with only 12" of available space.

Custom, or semi-custom, cabinets may be a solution. Shorter cabinets are routinely used above cooktops and refrigerators, and anything can be special ordered for a price. You can also mix and match - use shorter cabinets where you really need the space and taller (standard 30") cabinets where you don't.

If you have lots of floor space than another option is an island, peninsula or simply a section with no cabinets above it. I have a 5' counter on a brick wall with standard base cabinets and no upper cabinets, and there are plenty of things I'll do there (especially anything involving rolling out dough) that I can't and/or just won't do on the other counter areas because the large open space is much easier to work with than the rest of the counters which have cabinets above them and are broken into small sections by cooktop and sinks.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. That makes a lot of sense. I will try to mix and match depending on where they are in the kitchen. There will be a couple of spots 30" cabinets shouldn't be an issue... but aside from that may need to go with the shorter ones. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are not obligated to install your cabinets at any "customary" height used when installing cabinets in new construction.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, but I agree 100%

Answer (score 0):

Standard upper cabinet elevation is 18" above the countertops.

In the US you typically need a ceiling height of no less than 7'-0" in "habitable spaces," where the definition of "habitable space" includes cooking areas like your kitchen. See [IRC R305.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch03_SecR305.1). Your 6'-6" drop ceiling will fail inspection in any jurisdiction using the International Residential Code, which is very, very common in the US. There is an exception for girders and ducts hanging from the ceiling, so don't worry about those as long as they're at or above 6'-4".

The 7'-0" ceiling height requirement explains the unavailability of upper cabinets with heights less than 30". With standard counter height of 36" and standard space between counters and upper cabinets of 18", 36"+18"+30" = 84" = 7'-0".